# How to disable the sliding of menu of Action bar in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms

I am using MasterDetailPage and using Action Bar in it. I have disabled and hide logo, icon and back button of action bar. But when I try to swipe from left to right from left side a blank menu list opens. I don't know why it is happening. how I can disable this one for action bar. I don't want menu list that's why I disabled back button, icon.
How I can disable this sliding menu which is coming from left to right when I am swiping from left to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `MasterDetailPage` there is a Property called `IsGestureEnabled`.
Setting that to false should stop tracking the swipe gesture.