# Disable Gestures On Specific Page Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am looking to disable gestures for a specific page. I've came across many post suggesting to set MasterDetailPage's `IsGestureEnabled` to false to disable it. This works but for some reason not all the time.

At the moment I only want to disable gestures at the signin page, so on authentication I enable gestures, OnAppearing I disable.

The issue I'm coming across is that if the user switchs apps and comes back and signs out, the gestures are still enabled. It makes me think a different MasterDetailePage context is being triggered.

Has anyone came across this issue or has any guidance for me. I possibly think I am not understanding the lifecycle of the MasterDetailPage

Comment: I am not sure what you mean **I only want to disable gestures at the signin page, so on authentication I enable gestures, OnAppearing I disable.**, You have been emphasizing the MasterDetailPage, I don't know what it has to do with MasterDetailPage? Can you post code you have tryto do.

Comment: @CherryBu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147080/how-to-disable-the-sliding-of-menu-of-action-bar-in-xamarin-forms why I'm emphasizing MasterDetailPage. Page A, I want to disable gestures, every other page, have it enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable gestures on a specific page for MasterDetailed Page, I Suggest you try to use MassagingCenter to do this.

1.Using MassagingCenter from master-detailed page constructor:

```
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "DisableGesture", (sender) =>
        {
            if (sender == "0")
            {
                IsGestureEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsGestureEnabled = true;
            }
        });
```

2.When you navigate to specific page , and want to disable gesture, you can do this in content page  OnAppearing method.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Send<string>("0", "DisableGesture");


    }
```